# Почему Wine не работает на процессорах типа ARM?

Tags: arm, wine

Почему Wine не работает на процессорах типа ARM?

Comment: А почему он должен работать?

Comment: Неправда, Wine на ARM [работает](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM). Только нужно понимать, что x86-приложения не запустятся на ARM каким-то магическим образом